# SVM radial kernel performance

Tags: classification, svm, predictive-models, prediction

I have a data set of 20k + features and 100+ observations. I'm doing a binary classification. I tried to use the SVM with radial kernel and after some cv parameter search the best one I've gotten has an astounding missclassification rate of almost 60%, that's worse than random guessing. Am I just not finding the right tuning parameter or ?

Comment: Missclassification rate of 60% is very suspicious. Your algorithm is not only not working, it is actively working against you!

Answer (score 0):

First, mis-classification is 60% can be changed by flipping the prediction label in binary classification, then the mis-classification ratio will be 40%.

In addition, it is almost impossible to answer this question with such detail. We do not know the nature of the data. It is possible that 40% error rate is the best thing we can. Proving more details can be more helpful.